# What's the unit of latest_usage.cpu?

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I want to get a metric of the cpu usage of my docker-containers. Therefor I consume

```
/api/v2.0/summary/<container-name>?type=docker
```

The response looks like

```
{
  "/docker/...": {
    "timestamp": "2018-03-20T10:07:31.606821474Z",
    "latest_usage": {
       "cpu": 8,
       "memory": 1769402368
    }
  }
}
```

My idea was to use the `latest_usage.cpu`. But what is the unit of this field? Percent?

Is this field the right choice to monitor the cpu usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's percentage.

From cAdvisor source code:

```
cpuRate := (latest.Cpu - previous.Cpu) * secondsToMilliSeconds / uint64(elapsed)
LatestUsage.cpu = cpuRate
```

Comment: Thank you, Yuankun. You helped me alot.